# How to get listbox index

Tags: c#

This is an item on my listbox. After I press a button, it adds this to my listbox and I want to get the hh:mm index (10:58), but I think this only has one index. How can I do it?

This is the whole item:

[image: Listbox item image]

Comment: Always avoid stringly typing.  Create class to represent an item, it should have a Time property.  Its ToString() override should generate the string you want to see in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridView instead.

You can add columns (like your time hh:mm) and then get the current selected index time. Or you can get the selected index row string and code an algorithm to extract the hh:mm from your string.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to add some code ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and create an array with all the items that are inside the listbox, and from there, do whatever you want with it.